# Access object properties after they are assigned by another function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript, and I'm learning how to use OOP principals. I'm stuck on assigning object properties and then accessing them later. 
Let's say I have this function that assigns properties to an object "Car".

```
function assignProps()
{
Car.size="small";
Car.cost="expensive";
}
```

The object Car with empty properties because they are assigned from the function.

```
var Car =
{
size:"",
cost:"",
returnSize: function()
            {
           return this.size;
            },
returnCost: function()
            {
           return this.cost;
            },

}
```

Now, I want to call the function that assigned the value, and then access Car's properties. I tried doing this, but it obviously failed:

```
function accessProps()
{

assignProps();
console.log(Car.returnSize());
console.log(Car.returnCost());

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have a feeling that this might have to do with constructors or prototypes, but since there are so many ways to create custom objects in Javascript, the documentations are very confusing.

EDIT: By "fail" I mean that it outputs the blank instead of the newly assigned value
EDIT: I tried doing it this way as well, and it yielded the same result.

Comment: what failed?  what was the error message?  what line did it fail on, and what line does that correspond to in your code?

Comment: did you forget to call accessProps()?

Comment: Can u show the whole code in sequence? Where `Car` is being created and when `accessProps` is being called?

Comment: It probably failed because you don't/can't use `=` in an object literal declaration. You should be using `:`. For example: `var Car = { size: "", cost: "" };`

Comment: Depending on your browser, you should be using its built-in console like Developer Tools (or from an extension, like Firebug), and this could've been avoided

Comment: @Ian sorry, this isn't my actual code it was just an example. I have the colons in the right places. What failed was that it output empty, instead of "small."

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your code:

```
var Car = {
   size:"",
   cost:""
}
```

And if you look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JskBy/
It works as expected.

Full code:

```
function assignProps() {
    Car.size="small";
    Car.cost="expensive";
}

var Car ={
    size:"",
    cost:""
}
function accessProps(){
  assignProps();
  console.log(Car.size);
}

assignProps();
accessProps();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error on your car object initialization, should be

```
var Car = { size: "", cost: "" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 18, column 14: Extra comma.

Line 20, column 2: Missing semicolon.

Try to get a developing tool with JSLint/JSHint built-in (e.g. Notepad++ with add-on), it might help you with debugging problems like this.